# Http to https redirect

Tags: discussion, status-completed, ssl

I was wondering why in stackoverflow `http` version is not automatically redirected to `https` ? When I come from google search I always end up on `http`. But manually typing `https://stackoverflow.com` works, I mean ssl is installed, if so, why not to make a redirect so it will be more secure ?

Comment: Also, http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/

Comment: This is now the case: https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/